# How to realize a 32 bit register in 8 bit AVR processor?

Tags: assembly, avr

I should create a 32 bit adder but I don't know how to create a 32 bit register from 8 bit registers which are used by AVR ATmega169 in assembly.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the carry flag is for.

Add the lowest byte of each 32-bit number using the ADD instruction. That will place the carry (ninth bit) of the addition in the carry flag. Then you add each pair of higher bytes in turn using the ADC instruction. It will include the carry flag in the addition, and also put the next carry in it after the addition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very fine the AVR assembler but I had compiled a program that sums two uint32_t and the assembly results is in the following line:

```
lds r20,_ZZ4mainE1x
lds r21,_ZZ4mainE1x+1
lds r22,_ZZ4mainE1x+2
lds r23,_ZZ4mainE1x+3
lds r24,_ZZ4mainE1y
lds r25,_ZZ4mainE1y+1
lds r26,_ZZ4mainE1y+2
lds r27,_ZZ4mainE1y+3
add r24,r20
adc r25,r21
adc r26,r22
adc r27,r23
sts _ZZ4mainE4tled,r24
sts _ZZ4mainE4tled+1,r25
sts _ZZ4mainE4tled+2,r26
sts _ZZ4mainE4tled+3,r27
```

the C code is the following:

```
static uint32_t volatile x;
static uint32_t volatile y;
static uint32_t volatile tled;

tled=x+y;
```

The declarations volatile have been used to avoid the compiler optimizations which would generate a code containing the addition result!

The assembly code demonstrates how the compiler uses eight 8 bit registers to accomplish the required operation!